# image is not responsive with the header

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

the logo image fits nicely when the tab is full, but when i decreases the size of the tab, the logo doesnt stay inside the header

[image: image not responsive]

```html
<header class="">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"
        ><img
          src="assets/images/logoo.png"
          alt="logo"
          style="max-width:30%;height;"
      /></a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarResponsive"
        aria-controls="navbarResponsive"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html"
              >Home
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="products.html">Our Products</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Hi, can you post your CSS as well?

Comment: `style="max-width:30%;height;"` you don't set the height property, maybe it can be auto?